# Create Png in Windows8/C#

Tags: c#, image, png, windows-8

How I can create and save png-image in Windows8/C#? I find way without DirectX. Is there a way to render the set of XAML-primitives to png?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [BitmapEncoder class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapencoder.aspx) to create a PNG image.  Use the [PngEncoderId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapencoder.pngencoderid.aspx) as the Guid argument to [CreateAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br226212.aspx).  See [this sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Simple-Imaging-Sample-a2dec2b0).  See [this sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ApplicationData-sample-fb043eb2) for an example of how to save data.

There is no easy way to pickle the visual tree into an image like there is in Silverlight.

Comment: "no easy" - But is it possible?